# Temporal rolling mean in stars

Tags: raster, r, time, spatio-temporal-data, stars

I need to find temporal rolling means (or other stats - max, min, etc.) in `stars` spatial obects. For `stars` raster cubes, this would be directly analogous to the `calc(rasterBrick, function(x) movingFun(x, 3, mean))` available in the `raster` package. I could just use `raster` instead of `stars` if all I had were raster cubes. However, I'm really liking the ability of `stars` to handle vector data as well, and I have some multipolygon data with time slices in `stars` objects that I would also like to get rolling statistics on. For example, I might try to calculate the 3-day rolling mean for the values in each polygon.

I can use something like `aggregate(polygonStars, by = 'weeks', FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)` to get the mean over discrete time units, but `aggregate` aggregates rather than rolls. I've tried using `st_apply`, but haven't had success with feeding it a rolling function like `RcppRoll::roll_mean` (I'm unclear what exactly it's doing when I feed it a rolling function since it wants a single output, but it ends up replacing a dimension instead of the attribute values).

I've tried just shoving the objects into the rolling functions from `RcppRoll` and `zoo`, but they expect vectors, and I haven't found a way to tell them to operate along the 3rd dimension. If that's possible, I suppose I could take the `stars` objects apart into vectors, do the rolling calculations, and then put them back together, but that would be cumbersome, error prone, and slow.

Ideally, I'd remain in `stars`, but if there's not the possibility of getting rolling temporal means from `stars` objects, I'll switch to `raster` for the rasters, and seek a suggestion for the polygons with temporal layers.

To illustrate using the example from https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/, How do I get the rolling means for each pixel in the raster cube `prec` and each polygon in the vector cube `a`, as indicated by the last lines of this code (which don't work because I'm using functions from `raster` to show what I'm looking for)?

```r
# Modified from the data raster and vector time series example at
# https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/ to illustrate

library(stars)
library(tidyverse)

# Get the rasters: these look similar to what my data has
prec_file = system.file("nc/test_stageiv_xyt.nc", package = "stars")
(prec = read_ncdf(prec_file, curvilinear = c("lon", "lat"), ignore_bounds = TRUE))

# Get north carolina
sf::read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"), "nc.gpkg") %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(prec)) -> nc # transform from NAD27 to WGS84
nc_outline = st_union(st_geometry(nc))

# Do the aggregate to make polygons with temporal layers
a = aggregate(prec, by = nc, FUN = max)

# Rolling means over time 
# These don't work because the functions are from `raster`, but this is the sort
# of thing I want to do.
rastRoll <- calc(prec, function(x) movingFun(x, 3, mean))
vectRoll <- calc(a, function(x) movingFun(x, 3, mean))
```

Answer (score 3):

With `stars` of *raster* geometry, this is straightforward using `st_apply`. Any function, including `raster::movingFun`, can be applied on per-pixel basis, as follows:

```r
rastRoll = st_apply(prec, c("x", "y"), function(x) raster::movingFun(x, 3, mean))
plot(rastRoll)
```

[image]

With `stars` of *vector* geometry, I couldn't find a way to use `st_apply`. However, the following workaround applies `raster::movingFun` directly on the matrix of `stars` layer values:

```r
vectRoll = a
vectRoll[[1]] = t(apply(vectRoll[[1]], 1, function(x) raster::movingFun(x, 3, mean)))
plot(vectRoll, col = hcl.colors(12))
```

[image]